# bind9 reverse zone not updating correctly

Tags: dynamic, dns, dhcp

I've been trying to learn how to setup isc-dhcp-server and bind9 for dynamic dns service within my home LAN.  I've followed a few how-tos online and managed to get it working, with one exception that my reverse zone doesn't seem to be getting updated correctly.  I know it's not quite right because if I do `dig raspbmc.home` (forward lookup) I get an answer back with the correct IP address of my raspberry pi, which is 192.168.1.12, but if I do `dig -x 192.168.1.12` I don't get an answer.  Reverse lookups on any IP address in my subnet don't give any answer, except for the DNS/DHCP server itself which has a static IP address.  I ran `sudo rndc sync` to update my zone files.  Here is the forward zone file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 907200 ; 1 week 3 days 12 hours
home            IN SOA  IXTREME.home. justin.IXTREME.home. (
                7          ; serial
                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                38400      ; minimum (10 hours 40 minutes)
                )
            NS  IXTREME.home.
            A   192.168.1.2
$ORIGIN home.
$TTL 3600   ; 1 hour
android A   192.168.1.5
            TXT "317532858ab461b8e08e92465158353660"
iPad        A   192.168.1.10
            TXT "31fc08f1797f8ef06bf8bbd71c6889c2c3"
printer     A   192.168.1.3
            TXT "31445a58fc15ac8a0c45ca7f81d62dc2ba"
laptop      A   192.168.1.6
            TXT "31b7f1f9e90f391d8733427cd4f783363f"
$TTL 907200 ; 1 week 3 days 12 hours
IXTREME         A   192.168.1.2
$TTL 3600   ; 1 hour
iPhone      A   192.168.1.7
            TXT "31ff1a903b509d454737f163433b50e979"
raspbmc         A   192.168.1.12
            TXT "319a34a5c33f22852155f1d0d79d29b7c9"
```

And  the reverse zone file ...

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 907200 ; 1 week 3 days 12 hours
1.168.192.in-addr.arpa  IN SOA  IXTREME.home. justin.IXTREME.home. (
                7          ; serial
                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                604800     ; retry (1 week)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
            NS  IXTREME.home.
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 3600   ; 1 hour
10          PTR iPad.home.
12          PTR raspbmc.home.
3           PTR printer.home.
5           PTR android.home.
6           PTR laptop.home.
7           PTR iPhone.home.
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 907200 ; 1 week 3 days 12 hours
2           PTR IXTREME.home.
```

The line `$ORIGIN 1.168.192.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.` in the reverse zone file doesn't look right ... this should be `$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`.  This line has been added automatically by isc-dhcp-server.  Can anybody help me troubleshoot this?

Thanks - JJB

Comment: can you provide your dhcpd.conf and named.conf.local files to assist with investigating the cause of your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change ddns-rev-domainname to "in-addr.arpa." in your dhcpd.conf file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question was how to troubleshoot this. Answer is to replace ddns-rev-domainname from "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa." to "in-addr.arpa.". This error come from a popular article about setting up DNS and DHCP for local network.